# Plotting position in a grid

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a dynamic grid and a list of x and y scores for each person - with just these, how can I determine which "box" to place each person in?

As the grid is dynamic I am trying to figure out how to use an array to avoid having to hard code this - I am currently looping through all the people and adding them to an array containing x and y (I can rework this if it is easier). With these values, how can I then loop through the grid and choose who goes in each box? I suspect I am way over thinking but I just cannot get this to work.

For example, let's assume the grid is 7 x 5

```
Array ( ["Bob"] => Array ( ["x"] => 3 ["y"] => 4 )
Array ( ["Fred"] => Array ( ["x"] => 4 ["y"] => 2 )
Array ( ["Tom"] => Array ( ["x"] => 1 ["y"] => 5 )
Array ( ["Joan"] => Array ( ["2"] => 3 ["y"] => 3 )
```

If the grid is numbered from bottom left like:

```
29 30 31 32 33 34 35
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
8  9  10 11 12 13 14
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

then Bob should be in 24, Fred in 11, Tom in 29, Joan in 17 etc

How can I run a loop to place each person in the right location?

So far I have tried:

```
$xEach=100/$xMax/100;

$xArray=array();
for ($i=$xEach; $i<100; $i=$i+$xEach) {
    $xArray[]=$i;
}

$yEach=100/$yMax/100;

$yArray=array();
for ($i=$yEach; $i<100; $i=$i+$yEach) {
    $yArray[]=$i;
}


$x=array();
$y=array();

<loop through people>

    $originalValue=$res['value'];
    $axis=res['axis'];
    $name=$res['name'];

    if ($axis=="x") {
        $newValue=$originalValue/$xMax;
        $hit=0;
        foreach ($xArray as $value) {
            if ($newValue<$value&&$hit==0) {
                $hit++;
                $x["$originalValue"][]=$name;
            }
        }

    } else {
        $type="y";
        $newValue=$originalValue/$yMax;
        $hit=0;
        foreach ($yArray as $value) {
            if ($newValue<$value&&$hit==0) {
                $hit++;
                $y["$originalValue"][]=$name;
            }
        }
    }
</loop>

<div class="customgridwrapper">
    <?php 
        $box=0;
        for ($yLoop=$yMax; $yLoop>=$yMin; $yLoop--) { ?>
        <?php for ($xLoop=$xMin; $xLoop<=$xMax; $xLoop++) {
            $box++;
            ?>
            <div class="griditem">      
                <span><?=$box?></span>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes loads, have put some of the code above but this is about version 15 so it is getting very messed up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the problem. So to make it easier to understand, break it down into it's separate parts.

**Creating the grid**

So the first task is to create the grid. This can easily be represented with nested PHP arrays. However, one thing to bear in mind is that you want your grid to start from the bottom left, whereas for simplicity, we'll be building our grid from the top left. Don't worry though, we can easily work around this when we come to render the output.

The following function will create a grid with the specified number of `$columns` and `$rows`, initialising the cell `$value` accordingly.

```
function createGrid($columns, $rows)
{
    $grid = [];
    $value = 1;

    for ($r = 0; $r < $rows; $r++) {
        $row = [];

        for ($c = 0; $c < $columns; $c++) {
            $row[] = $value++;
        }

        $grid[] = $row;
    }

    return $grid;
}
```

**Plotting the values**

Your values are based on cartesian coordinates, which start from `1, 1`. Our grid, because it's based on PHP arrays is actually zero indexed, so starts from `0, 0`. Therefore when plotting the values on the grid, we'll need to decrement the `$x` and `$y` values by one to map them accordingly.

```
$values = [
    'bob' => [3, 4],
    'fred' => [4, 2],
    'tom' => [1, 5],
    'joan' => [3, 3],
];

function plotGridValues($grid, $values)
{
    foreach ($values as $value => $coordinates) {
        list($x, $y) = $coordinates;
        $grid[$y - 1][$x - 1] = $value;
    }

    return $grid;
}
```

**Render the grid**

We mentioned before that you want your grid rendered from the bottom left, whereas we have created it to start from the top left. Before rendering it, we need to fix this, and it can be easily achieved using `array_reverse`.

I hate mixing PHP and HTML in this manner, but for the sake of simplicity, I have `echo`d out the HTML in a `<table>`.

```
function renderGrid($grid) 
{
    $grid = array_reverse($grid);

    echo "<table>\r\n";

    foreach ($grid as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';

        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            echo "<td>{$cell}</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>\r\n";
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

**The complete code**

Go wild!

```
<?php

$values = [
    'bob' => [3, 4],
    'fred' => [4, 2],
    'tom' => [1, 5],
    'joan' => [3, 3],
];

$grid = createGrid(7, 5);
$grid = plotGridValues($grid, $values);
echo renderGrid($grid);

function createGrid($columns, $rows)
{
    $grid = [];
    $cell = 1;

    for ($r = 0; $r < $rows; $r++) {
        $row = [];

        for ($c = 0; $c < $columns; $c++) {
            $row[] = $cell++;
        }

        $grid[] = $row;
    }

    return $grid;
}

function plotGridValues($grid, $values)
{
    foreach ($values as $value => $coordinates) {
        list($x, $y) = $coordinates;
        $grid[$y - 1][$x - 1] = $value;
    }

    return $grid;
}

function renderGrid($grid) 
{
    $grid = array_reverse($grid);

    echo "<table>\r\n";

    foreach ($grid as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';

        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            echo "<td>{$cell}</td>";
        }

        echo "</tr>\r\n";
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Yes, like you said and even I mentioned in my original post I was overthinking it - I need to add some additional bits in like dealing with scenarios when the values are greater than the size of the grid etc but this is a fabulous start!